# Execute shell in php, but have the page update as output is generated

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, shell

This is an html page using jquery/ajax to call php which calls a c program to update the page without needing to do a refresh.

I have a from for the user to enter data in called **input_form**:

```
<form id="input_form" name="input_form">
... code ...
</form>
```

Next I have a Jquery function to output the data to a text box when the form button is clicked:

```
//send all of the form data to php and print php's response
$(document).ready(function(){

    //the current request
    var request;

    //what happens the form submit button is clicked
    $("#input_form").submit(function(event){

        //if a request is currently going on, abort this new request
        if (request) {request.abort();}

        var serializedData = $(this).serialize();

        //disable inputs while the request is going on
        var $inputs = $(this).find("input, select, button, textarea");
        $inputs.prop("disabled", true);

        //perform the request and send the output to a div
        request = $.ajax({
            type: "get",
            url: "ajax.php",
            data: serializedData,
            success: function(result){
                $('#answer').val(result);
            }
        });

        //re-enable all of the inputs now that the request is over
        request.always(function () {$inputs.prop("disabled", false);});

        //prevent default posting on the form
        return event.preventDefault();
    });

});
```

---

Over on the php side, I take in all the form data, and pass them to a c program, wait for the output, and then echo it back:

```
<?php
$program_statement = './main';
$program_statement .= ' --amount=' . escapeshellarg($_GET['amount']);
$program_statement .= ' --max=' . escapeshellarg($_GET['max']);
$program_statement .= ' --min=' . escapeshellarg($_GET['min']);

$output=shell_exec($program_statement);
echo $output;
?>
```

**Question:**
This program could take a long time to run.  Is there a way to get the output to display on the page, as it is being outputted to the shell?  The function [shell_exec](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) simply has no choice but to wait.  How is synchronous updating like I want usually done?  Have I done anything that you think is just the wrong approach, or is against best practices?

Here is a [link to the project](https://github.com/luxe/random-number/tree/72ef084dba976c73ac10d670e7ee9d640949e7f9).
Here is a [link to the server](http://csgenis.com/trevor/random-number/) it is currently running on.

Comment: how about having the shell app write to a file or db, and use js to poll that periodically?

Comment: "Please don't use numbers longer than 15 characters long." how does that reconcile with the claim of  "Infinitely large random numbers!"

Comment: "ERROR: the argument ('1000000000000000000') for option '--amount' is invalid
generates random numbers:
  --min arg             minimum number that can be generated
  --max arg             maximum number that can be generated
  --amount arg          the amount of numbers to generate
  -h [ --help ]         produce this help message
  -v [ --version ]      display version"

Comment: @Dragon I didn't want the server to crash by having too many programs running! D:

Comment: i like crashing people server, that iswhy i held down the 9 key for a real long time in your form :-)